# Solved! Get value from one query and use it in other query

Tags: apex, class

This class allow me to get the bundleItems where the bundle_*c matches the ProductId, I need to get the QtyOrdered from the List values and somehow multiply the QtyOrdered by Qty*_c. I am populating the vf page pageblock using the PODetails2.

```
public PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems (ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl2){ 
    std2=stdCtrl2;

    List<Purchase_Order_Details__c> values  = [SELECT ProductId__c, QtyOrdered__c  
                                               FROM Purchase_Order_Details__c 
                                               WHERE PO_ID__c =:std2.getId()];


    String[] contractIDs = new string[values.size()];

    for (integer i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
       contractIDs[i] = values[i].ProductId__c ;
    }

    PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c, Qty__c,Total__c,
                         Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c, 
                         Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c, 
                         Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c  
                  FROM o_Bundle__c
                  WHERE Bundle__c  IN:contractIDs  ];
```

VF Code:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PODetails2}" var="b" styleClass="LinesTable2" rowClasses="even,odd" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="3">
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="NRCode" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="SKU" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/> 
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Description" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Qty" value="{!b.Qty__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Rate" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Total" headerClass="LeftAlign Gray"> 
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,$###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!b.Qty__c*b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />              
            </apex:outputText> 
        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>>
```

Comment: Can you add VF code of where you use PODetails?  I think the solution is to create a 'wrapper' class, but I need to confirm how you are planning to use it

Comment: Let me explain you, for this pdf report there is a table that displays the Single items and a second table that displays that bundle Items, now the Bundle is usually 1 but when that is more than 1 then the system needs to multiply the bundleItems qty by the qtyOrdered of the bundle.

Comment: Can you put the VF code for the whole dataTable?  You'll need to know all the columns you want to display before we can write a wrapper class to group up the data for the table

Comment: <apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PODetails2}" var="b" styleClass="LinesTable2" rowClasses="even,odd" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="3">
             <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="NRCode" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>

Comment: <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="SKU" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
             <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Description" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
              <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Qty" value="{!b.Qty__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
             <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Rate" value="{!b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>

Comment: <apex:column headerValue="Total" headerClass="LeftAlign Gray">
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,$###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!b.Qty__c*b.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>       </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>>

Comment: sorry I pasted it here, for some reason I can't edit the original code

Comment: I added the code.  You get 'edit' privilege at like 100 points or something.  So, what info do you need to put in the table that you **can't** get from o_Bundle__c?  (cause that's what the table is looping over)

Comment: I posted a image of the vf page, so you can see the code and the table. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok thank you.  The Qty_c from PODetails2 needs to be multiplied by the QtY_Ordered__c which is in the list values.

Comment: I am getting this error:Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'purchasOrderDetailId' at line 4 column 18.     This is the line 4: private final purchasOrderDetailId;
 







Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'purchasOrderDetailId' at line 4 column 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place to add a wrapper class.  A 'wrapper' class is jargon for a subclass within your controller.  They're just like regular classes except these subclasses cannot have static methods.

Here's your controller cleaned up a bit, and I replaced some of your code with some standard practices.  The trick is to create a 'wrapper' class where each instance of the wrapper class has (1) the `o_Bundle__c` record like normal and (2) the quantity as mapped.  Now, I think I have the relationship between `Purchase_Order_Details__c` and `o_Bundle__c` right, but you should double check.  Also, I used a `map` in there, and if you haven't used `maps` yet, now is the best time to start using them.  `Maps` **always** make life easier; they're the awesome in the awesome sauce.

```
public class PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems {

    private final id purchasOrderDetailId;
    public list<data> dataList {get;set;}

    public PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems (ApexPages.StandardController con){ 
        // initialize variables
        this.purchasOrderDetailId=con.getId();
        this.dataList=new list<data>();    

        list<Purchase_Order_Details__c> purchaseOrderDetailList= [SELECT ProductId__c, QtyOrdered__c  
                                                                  FROM Purchase_Order_Details__c
                                                                  WHERE PO_ID__c =:purchasOrderDetailId];
        map<id,decimal> quantityMap=new map<id,decimal>(); // quantityMap: productId -----> quantity
        for(Purchase_Order_Details__c p:purchaseOrderDetailList)
            quantityMap.put(p.ProductId__c,p.QtyOrdered__c);

        list<o_Bundle__c> PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c, Qty__c,Total__c,
                                               Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c, 
                                               Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c, 
                                               Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c,
                                               Bundle__c  
                                        FROM o_Bundle__c
                                        WHERE Bundle__c IN :quantityMap.keySet()];

        for(o_Bundle__c b:PODetails2)
            dataList.add(new data(b,quantityMap.get(b.Bundle__c)));
    }//END init(ApexPages.StandardController con)

    public class data{
        public o_Bundle__c bundle {get;set;}
        public decimal quantity {get;set;}

        // constructor
        public data(o_Bundle__c bundle,decimal quantity){
            this.bundle=bundle;
            this.quantity=quantity;
        }//END init(o_Bundle__c bundle,decimal quantity)
    }//END data

}//END PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems
```

on the VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dataList}" var="d" styleClass="LinesTable2" rowClasses="even,odd" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="3">
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="NRCode" value="{!d.bundle.Bundle_Item__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="SKU" value="{!d.bundle.Bundle_Item__r.WarehouseCode__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/> 
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Description" value="{!d.Bundle.Bundle_Item__r.Product_Name__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Qty" value="{!b.Qty__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/>
        <apex:column headerClass="LeftAlign Gray" headerValue="Rate" value="{!d.Bundle.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" styleClass="LeftAlign"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Total" headerClass="LeftAlign Gray"> 
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,$###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!d.bundle.Qty__c*d.bundle.Bundle_Item__r.NRPrice__c}" />              
            </apex:outputText> 
        </apex:column> 

        <apex:column headerValue="QuantityOrderd X Quantity" headerClass="LeftAlign Gray"> 
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number,$###,###,##0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!d.bundle.Qty__c*d.quantity}" />              
            </apex:outputText> 
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>>
```

Comment: wow.. let me test please.. I will get back to you soon..Thank you!

Comment: I am getting this error:Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'purchasOrderDetailId' at line 4 column 18. This is the line 4: private final purchasOrderDetailId; Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'purchasOrderDetailId' at line 4 column 18

Comment: when declaring the variable, i forgot the variable type.  it should read "private final id purchasOrderDetailId".  I updated my code

Comment: do you see any error here:  WHERE Bundle__c quantityMap.keySet()];

 for(o_Bundle__c b:PODetails2)
 dataList.add(new data(b,quantityMap.get(b.Bundle__c)));

Comment: yea, sorry O_O I forgot the "IN clause"  I updated the code again

Comment: I think here WHERE Bundle__c quantityMap.keySet()]; (Do I need to add a IN or =:) and here it needs to be a DOt instead of comma?(b,quantityMap.get(b.Bundle__c)));

Comment: "WHERE Bundle__c IN :quantityMap.keySet()];"  you need both.  "IN" because we want all records with Bundle__c-ids that are also in the quantityMap.keySet(), and we need to prefix quantityMap.keySet() with ":" because we are referencing a controller variable in a SOQL query

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: data at line 3 column 17                                                      This line 3 public list<data> dataList {get;set;}

Comment: did you add the "data" class like I did in my solution?  Make sure to scroll down to the bottom

Comment: No I missed it....

Comment: AmatorVitae, for some rwason in the VF Page the tables is empty, its like is not getting any data. My guess is that maybe in this line something is wrong:for(o_Bundle__c b:PODetails2)
            dataList.add(new data(b,quantityMap.get(b.Bundle__c)));

Comment: AmatorVitae, I found the problem, it was the private final id purchasOrderDetailId; so I changed with my old code  private ApexPages.StandardController std2; and it works PERFECTLY

Comment: Amator, I don't know how to thank you.. I wouldn't be able to do it without your help. Thank you , thank you , thank you so much.

Comment: Amator, I hope you are doing well. could you please help me with the last question I asked. I will really appreciate it! hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a image of the vf Page and its code